# Change image button icon color to grayscale at Runtime using C# Code

Tags: c#

we are developing an erp application using WPF which is currently still at the initial stages.

i need to know how to change the color of the .png or .jpg icon to grayscale at runtime using C# code for a particular childwindow instance.

for example, a window handling edit operation should have save image button disabled and turned in to grayscale.

help very much appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I use this extension method to convert an image to grayscale:

```
public static Image MakeGrayscale(this Image original)
{
    Image newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);
    ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(
        new float[][] 
        {
            new float[] {0.299f, 0.299f, 0.299f, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0.587f, 0.587f, 0.587f, 0, 0},
            new float[] {.114f, .114f, .114f, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        });

    ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
    attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);
    g.DrawImage(
        original, 
        new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
        0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, 
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

    g.Dispose();
    return newBitmap;
}
```